# Updating value within my .Json every time my test runs

Tags: c#

I have a specflow test that uses a .json but within the .json the ID value has to be unique every time it runs. How can i set it so the ID is updated with a new guid every time the test runs. Below is my method i'm using.

I've tried to include the below within the test but it doesn't seem to capture it within the test

```
Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
[When(@"I receive a file([\w\s]+) notification with information([\w\s]+)")]
public void WhenIReceiveNotification(string code, string tnCode)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> names = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "REFUND","Refund.json"},
```

I expect the ID field within my .json to be updated every time my test runs.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be deserializing the JSON, replacing the ID yourself and serializing it back again, e.g.

```
[When(@"I receive a file([\w\s]+) notification with information([\w\s]+)")]
public void WhenIReceiveNotification(string code, string tnCode)
{
    string fileName = "Refund.json";
    string newId = ReplaceId(fileName);
    Dictionary<string, string> names = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "REFUND", fileName}
    };

    // ... your logic
}

private void ReplaceId(string fileName) {

    // Read file content and parse the JSON into an object
    string json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

    // Replace the ID with a new one.
    string newId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    obj.Id = newId;

    // Serialize the object with the new ID, and write it back to the file
    string newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, newJson);

    // Return the new file name to the caller.
    return newId;
}
```

*Note: The `JsonConvert` class can be found in the Json.NET library (Newtonsoft.Json). I used this to keep it simple, you can use any JSON de/serialization library.*